# How to populate a DeserializationContext with domain-specific objects so they can be used during deserialisation?

Tags: java, json, jackson

### DOMAIN

There are two classes `ProjectSchema` and `PageSchema`. The latter is dependent on the former.

```
class ProjectSchema {}
class PageSchema {
    public PageSchema(ProjectSchema schema) {}
}
```

These classes represent JSON configuration files and both have custom `JsonDeserializer`s.

```
class PageSchemaDeserialiser extends JsonDeserializer<PageSchema> {
    @Override
    public PageSchema deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) {}
}
```

### PROBLEM

To completely initialise a `PageSchema` object in the `PageSchemaDeserialiser`, I need an instance of `ProjectSchema` there.

When I start parsing a `TreeNode` into a `PageSchema`, I have a `ProjectSchema` constructed

```
ProjectSchema projectSchema = ...;
... 
new ObjectMapper().treeToValue(node, PageSchema.class);
```

and I want to let the deserialiser know about it. I saw there is `DeserializationContext` the `deserialize` method takes. I am wondering if I am able to pass the project schema there, so it will be available during page schema construction.

### QUESTION

That boils down to a question:

**How to populate a `DeserializationContext` with domain-specific objects so they can be used during deserialisation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time before I found out that `DeserializationContext` contains `InjectableValues` and I can pass them in through an `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setInjectableValues(new InjectableValues.Std(myMap));

PageSchema schema = mapper.readValue(inputStream, PageSchema.class);
```

In `PageSchemaDeserialiser`, I call

```
Object myValue = context.findInjectableValue("myKey", null, null);
```

It solves the problem, yet brings a new one. I now should keep track of `InjectableValues` in my shared `ObjectMapper` instance.